# Miles per Hour Calculator

Tags: java, calculator

Here is what I have so far I need to get the miles per hour to be a number with no decimals after it and I am stuck on how to do so. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

P.S. I'm sorry if I posted this wrong its my first time

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MilesPerHour
{
    private int distance, hours, minutes;
    private double mph;

    public MilesPerHour()
    {
        setNums(0,0,0);
        mph=0;
    }

    public MilesPerHour(int dist, int hrs, int mins)
    {
        distance = dist;
        hours = hrs;
        minutes = mins;

    }

    public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins)
    {


    }

    public void calcMPH()
    {

        mph = (distance)/(hours + (minutes/60.0));

    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(distance + " miles in " + hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes = " + mph + "MPH.");

    }

    public static void main( String[] args )

    {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
        int dist = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
        int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
        int mins = keyboard.nextInt();

        MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins);
        test.calcMPH();
        test.print();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
public void calcMPH()
{

    mph = Math.round((distance)/(hours + (minutes/60.0)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void calcMPH()
{

    mph = Math.round((distance)/(hours + (minutes/60.0));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Java: Use DecimalFormat to format doubles and integers but keep integers without a decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309189/java-use-decimalformat-to-format-doubles-and-integers-but-keep-integers-without)

This should explain how to format numbers exactly as you'd want them. In your case, using setMaximumFractionDigits(0) would be appropriate.

The linked response is of course advanced (but still a good method to know), and there are several easier ways to tackle your specific usecase.

```
Math.round(your_mph);
```

and

```
Math.floor(your_mph);
```

would both work, as well as typecasting (this is a horrible approach however, and you should avoid doing so.)

```
mph = (int) mph_calculation;
```

If you plan on making a larger application with more number-juggling, i'd recommend going for the linked response. If it's just this one usecase, using the quick Math functions are probably a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public void calcMPH()
{
    mph = Math.round(distance/1.609);
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained anything about what original code was doing, why that wasn’t correct, and why this is better.